# Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia GTX 750 not recognized

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, resolution

I've recently installed 14.04 on a new system. All is up and running but ubuntu doesn't seem to want to recognize my nvidia card. It is recognized and display is active via VGA, but I am unable to set proper display resolution (1920x1080). Under Software and Updates --> Additional Drivers it lists "NVIDIA Corporation: Unknown". Currently have the nvidia 340 driver installed and showing active, but I am not getting access to all card functionality (display resolution in particular). I have gone through multiple driver purges and reinstalls to no avail. Any idea what's going on here??

Much appreciated.
A

Comment: We may need to know exactly **how** you installed **which** drivers (subversion may matter), and if you had installed `nvidia-settings` of the same version too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I installed via ppa as the following
sudo add-get-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudu apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

I did not install nvidia-settings...

thank you for the assistance!
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340

Answer (score 1):

Together with the latest proprietary nvidia driver we may also install `nvidia-settings` from the xorg-edgers ppa. This ensures the setting application matches our driver version.

Then we may change the screen resolution from the *XServer Display Configuration* tab:

[image]

Note that on installing from xorg-edgers ppa we should take care to only install the nvidia drivers but not other X components also maintained by this ppa because these may introduce instabilities to our system. In case we had accidentaly run an upgrade on all packages we need to run `ppa-purge` to restore to default packages.

Then we may again add the ppa, install the nvidia driver **only** to then deactivate the ppa again. This makes sure we do not install possibly unstable other X components.

Answer (score 0):

Assistance much appreciated. I followed your guidance, reinstalling the driver, and still had the same issue.
I decided to do a fresh install with 14.10 today and the problem looks to be resolved. The card is recognized properly and I'm able to adjust to 1920x1080 resolution through the advanced settings in nvidia settings. Thanks for the help!